# How can I apply an Action to more than one object in a Workshop table?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-actions

I have a object table widget in workshop which is filtered by a filter list widget. Once filtered down to a selection of objects, I would like to apply an action to all of them. However, I am currently only able to apply an action to one of them at a time. Is it possible to apply an action to several objects at once?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. When you are configuring your action, be sure to toggle on the Allow multiple values switch for the primary key.
[image]
Then, when creating your object table be sure to toggle on `Enable Multi-Select` in your widget settings. Be sure to correctly configure your selected objects below it so that the output refers to all selected rows.
[image]
Finally, configure the parameter defaults of your button with an action so that the default value for the objects is the same output as the multi-select objects.
[image]